# Geometry Nodes: How to make a adjustable stepped "stairs" math function?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to make a adjustable stepped "stairs" math function?

Like **[this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wuo2omzg7m)** one, including the adjustable stair corners:

[image]

**[This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269516/8282)** was a great answer but the smoothness of the steps needs to be animatable also.

Answer (score 5):

By using that function mentioned in the image of the question and this below information I was able to make the nodes in Blender geometry nodes:

[image]

Here are the essential nodes:

[image]

**[Here](https://twitter.com/manujarvinen/status/1668316487365414913)**'s a video of it in action.

Simple example .blend:

[image]

The video's .blend:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your self-answer!